# Remove LAMMP with PHP7 in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: apache2, php, mint

There was an error and I want to completly start over. is there any way to completly remove LAMMP with PHP7 on it? or it just same way as removing LAMMP with PHP5?

this will completly remove LAMMP with PHP5

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server apache2 php5
```

and

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient15off libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libpq5 mysql-client-5.0 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.0 php5-common php5-mysql
```

it will do in LAMMP with PHP5, how do i remove LAMMP with PHP7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove all php7 packages as well check the installed packages with `apt list --installed | grep "php"` and remove them.